# Passing data to parent in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I'm new to React and thus the question.
I have a parent Component - HomePage with a child Component - SideBar.

My child component sidebar needs to pass a data back to the parent on a submit button click which the parent needs to post on an api.

This my parent component,

```
class HomePage extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
    .......
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleSubmit(){
  //Logic to get the data from the child and post to localhost:8080/
  }
  render(){
    return(

        <div className="col-md-2 left-pane">
          <Sidebar handleSubmitButton={this.state.handleSubmit}/>
        </div>

    );
  }

}
```

This is my child component,

```
class Sidebar extends React.Component {

  handleSubmitButton(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

          <input type="text"/>

            <button type="button" className="btn btn-info btn-icons" onClick={this.props.handleSubmitButton} >
              <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-send" aria-hidden="true"/>
            </button>


      </div>
    );

  }
}

Sidebar.propTypes = {
  handleSubmitButton: React.PropTypes.func
};
```

My question is how do I grab the input text with the onclick method on the sidebar button click and pass it up to the parent to post it on an api. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your child component you can create a property for the ref attribute. Accessing DOM elements directly is usually done by setting refs.

In your parent component you can use an arrow function with a callback which allows you to access the `<input>` DOM element anywhere within your parent component, by simply typing this.textInput

More information about refs can be found in the official React documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Parent component:

```
handleSubmit() {
  console.log(this.textInput.value);
}

<Sidebar 
  inputRef={(input) => this.textInput = input} 
  handleSubmitButton={this.state.handleSubmit}
/>
```

Child component:

```
<input ref={this.props.inputRef} type="text"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

Your parent Component should not access the input directly, but rather rely on the child component to pass any values to the parent when required.

```
class HomePage extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(textInputValue){
    // The callback passed to the child component will
    // submit the data back to it's parent.
    // Logic to post to localhost:8080/
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="col-md-2 left-pane">
        <Sidebar handleSubmitButton={ this.handleSubmit }/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Sidebar extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    this.handleSubmitButton = this.handleSubmitButton.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmitButton(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // By giving the input the `ref` attribute, we can access it anywhere
    const textInputValue = this.refs.input.value;

    // Submit the value to the parent component
    this.props.handleSubmitButton(textInputValue);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" ref="input" />

        <button type="button" className="..." onClick={this.handleSubmitButton} >
          <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-send" aria-hidden="true"/>
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This prevents coupling your components together and will ease testing later.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple ways you can go about it. One is you can add an onChange event to the input to update state of the Sidebar component. Then when the submit handler is clicked, pass the value from state, and have the HomePage handleSubmit() accept the value.

The other is to also pass an onChange prop from the HomePage component to the Sidebar. The input would then set the onChange to that prop.